# ASP.NET MVC and Javascript - Submit button submitting form, onclick @URL.Action not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have two submits, one to submit the form on page 1, the other to submit form on page 1 and redirect to form 2 on page 2.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit and Add Expense" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Expense")';"/>
```

The issue is, when this secondary submit button is clicked it just submits the form just like the first submit button. It appears that the redirect @url.action is not firing. Thoughts?

Comment: Don't have it be a submit button. A submit button is designed to submit the form with no other interaction. You can `preventDefault` in your onclick event, but then you're not technically using a submit anymore anyway.

Comment: I guess the better question should be, what would be the best way of submitting and redirecting in a situation like this? Looking at this more closely, it appears that I'm able to do one or the other.

Comment: So you want the 2nd button to post, like normal submit, but after that then redirect, whereas the first button just post like normal and keep on same page?

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger that's correct. The first button works as expected as it's just a basic type="submit".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Comment: ^ I'll give this a go. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do the trick.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnOne" value="One"/>

<input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="One"/>

<script>
    var sample = sample || {};
    sample.url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Expense")';
</script>

//you can move it to a separate file
<script>
$(function(){

    $("#btnTwo").click(function(){

        var form = $("form");
        form.submit();

         setTimeout(function() {


            window.location.href = sample.url;
        },100);


    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. this didn't actually work though. clicking the secondary button, form didn't submit nor did it redirect to the expense page.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going the easy route of assigning value property to the button, and then checking the button value in the controller.

// View

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<button name="button" value="SubmitAndExpense">Submit and Add Expense</button>
```

// Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string button)
{
   if (button != "SubmitAndExpense") {...}
}
```